# How to include jsp pages using Spring form tag?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-annotations

I'm using Spring, in that I have `user.jsp`

`user.jsp` has three separate divisons: 1. Personal,  2. Educational,  3. Awards. Each section has different forms .jsp that I have created.

Now I'm thinking to include these three forms into `user.jsp` and display Model using one Controller.

Here is my controller class code:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping(value="profile")
public class UserProfileController {

    @RequestMapping(value="user", method=RequestMethod.GET)
    public String user(Model model) throws Exception {
        model.addAttribute("profile", new PersonalForm());

        return "profile/user";
    }
```

And this is my Personal.jsp file (all remaining files are the same but names are different)

So how to include these three jsp into `user.jsp`? Actually I'm trying but Eclipse is showing an error. Below is my error code in `user.jsp`:

> Fragment "profile/professional.jsp" was not found at
>   expected path /EClass/WebContent/WEB-INF/ 
>   pages/profile/profile/professional.jsp

So please help me how to include and how to work with single controller?

Comment: Could you please post view resolver configuration from your context xml file ?

Comment: @Jeevan patil .. once see my edit code..

Comment: I don't see you including professional.jsp anywhere in other jsp's. Then how can you get this error?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In your User.jsp write following code...

```
        <%@ taglib prefix="form" uri="http://www.springframework.org/tags/form"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>

<fieldset id="profile_proffiesional">
    <form:form action="profile/user" modelAttribute="profile">
        <jsp:include page="personal.jsp"></jsp:include>
        <jsp:include page="educational.jsp"></jsp:include>
        <jsp:include page="awards.jsp"></jsp:include>
    </form:form>
</fieldset>
```